# WinError 32 While trying to delete Temp folder contents with Python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to setup a script that will delete all files in the temp folder on startup, but I continue to get "Reason [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Here is what I am running:

```
import os, shutil, winshell

tempPath = r'C:\Users\JAMES~1.W_U\AppData\Local\Temp'
tempDelete = os.listdir(tempPath)

for file in tempDelete:
    tempDeletePath = os.path.join(tempPath, file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(tempDeletePath) or os.path.islink(tempDeletePath):
            os.unlink(tempDeletePath)
        elif os.path.isdir(tempDeletePath):
            shutil.rmtree(tempDeletePath)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to delete %s. Reason %s' % (tempDeletePath, e))
```

I believe the `shutil.rmtree(tempDeletePath)` process is working, but I am getting the WinError 32 with the files. I understand it believes it is running within another process, and have tried closing the process as well, but I do not know if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Why do you think you have to delete everything in %temp%?

Comment: Many different processes use the `%TEMP%` folder. If another process has a file opened, you shouldn't try to delete it. Instead of `rmtree` you can walk the directory manually, deleting single files in a `try/except` block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restart OS and try again?

Also, 1 way to try troubleshoot/get more details is

```
import os
import glob

glob_wild_card = os.path.join(tempPath, "*.*")

for file in glob.glob(glob_wild_card):
   try:
      os.remove(file)
   except Exception as e:
      print(f"Error is {e} from {file}")
```

from the logs, you can find out which is file with problem and hopefully you can find out which is the process locked to that file.